# Solve the differential equation: $6 \cos^2(x) \dfrac{dy}{dx} -y \sin(x)+2y^4 \sin^3(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation before me:
$6 \cos^2(x) \dfrac{dy}{dx} -y \sin(x)+2y^4 \sin^3(x)=0$

I tried solving it by reducing to Bernoulli form of first order differential equation.
I divided both sides of the equation by $6 \cos^2(x)y^4$ to get:

$\dfrac{1}{y^4} \dfrac{dy}{dx}-\dfrac{1}{y^3} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{6\cos^2(x)}=\dfrac{-\sin^3(x)}{3\cos^2(x)}$

Then I took $\dfrac{1}{y^3}=z$
so that $\dfrac{-3}{y^4}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dz
}{dx}$

This gave me:

$\dfrac{dz}{dx}+\dfrac{\sin(x)}{2\cos^2(x)}z=\dfrac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$

This is first order linear differential equation of the type
$ \dfrac{dz}{dx}+P(x)z=Q(x)$

Integrating Factor (IF) is given by:

$IF=e^{\int P(x) \,dx}= e^{\int \dfrac{\sin(x)}{2\cos^2(x)}\,dx}= e^{\dfrac{1}{2\cos(x)}}$

Next, solution is given by:

$z.IF= \int IF.Q(x)$
or
$z.e^{\dfrac{1}{2\cos(x)}}=\int e^{\dfrac{1}{2\cos(x)}}.\dfrac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \,dx$

This is the step where I falter as I find myself unable to tackle the integral on the RHS of the above equation.
You are requested to help me with the evaluation of this integral or come up with another way of tackling this differential equation. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: its a pretty hard question....the result is somewhat intimidating...you'll see when i'll write the solution

Comment: Perhaps it is not doable by hand.

Comment: @ZAhmed i dont think so

Answer (score 1):

As @abcdefu already did, after $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{u}}$, we have
$$2 \cos ^2(x)\, u'+ \sin (x)\, u=2 \sin ^3(x)$$

The solution of the homegeneous is simple
$$u=C\,e^{-\frac{\sec (x)}{2}}$$ Variation of parameters leads to
$$\cos ^2(x) e^{-\frac{\sec (x)}{2}} C'=\sin ^3(x) \implies C'=\sin (x) \tan ^2(x) \,e^{\frac{\sec (x)}{2}}$$

Now, using $\sec(x)=2t$
$$C'=2 e^t \left(1-\frac{1}{4 t^2}\right) \implies C=\frac{1}{2} \left(e^t \left(\frac{1}{t}+4\right)-\text{Ei}(t)\right)+\text{Constant}$$

Answer (score 0):

I am writing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $y'$

Our equation is $$6\operatorname{cos}^2(x)y'=\operatorname{sin}(x)y-2\operatorname{sin}^3(x)y^4$$ $=$
$$y'-\frac{\operatorname{sin}(x)y}{6\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}=-\frac{\operatorname{sin}^3(x)y^4}{3\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}$$ Dividing by $y^4$,
$$\frac{y'}{y^4}-\frac{\operatorname{sin}(x)}{6\operatorname{cos}^2(x)y^3}=-\frac{\operatorname{sin}^3(x)}{3\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}$$
Let $u=\frac{1}{y^3}$ therefore $y=\frac{1}{u^{\frac13}}$ and $u'=\frac{-3y'}{y^4}$ and $y'=\frac{-u'y^4}{3}$

Substituting all the values, our equation becomes $$-\frac{u\operatorname{sin}(x)}{6\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}-\frac{u'}{3}=-\frac{\operatorname{sin}^3(x)}{3\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{u\operatorname{sin}(x)}{2\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}+u'=\frac{\operatorname{sin}^3(x)}{\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}$$ Let $u=tv$ where $t,v$ are two functions $\implies$ $u'=tv'+t'v$ Rewriting the equation in terms of functions and then grouping we get, $$tv'+v\left(\frac{t\operatorname{sin}(x)}{2\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}+t'\right)=\frac{\operatorname{sin}^3(x)}{\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}$$ Solving the first equation $$\left(\frac{t\operatorname{sin}(x)}{2\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}+t'\right)=0$$ By seeing the work that you showed in your question, I am pretty sure you can calculate this equation easily. So after solving we get $$t=\frac{1}{\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e}$$ Now solving the second equation $$tv'+v\left(\frac{t\operatorname{sin}(x)}{2\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}+t'\right)=\frac{\operatorname{sin}^3(x)}{\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}$$ at $$t=\frac{1}{\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e}$$ and$$\left(\frac{t\operatorname{sin}(x)}{2\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}+t'\right)=0$$ Therefore the second equation becomes $$\frac{v'}{\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e}=\frac{\operatorname{sin}^3(x)}{\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}$$ After transforming things $$dv=\frac{\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e\operatorname{sin}^3(x)\:\:dx}{\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}$$ Integrating both sides,
$$\int1\cdot dv=\int\frac{\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e\operatorname{sin}^3(x)\:\:dx}{\operatorname{cos}^2(x)}$$ $\implies$
$$v=-\frac{\operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{2\operatorname{cos}(x)}\right)}{2}+\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e\operatorname{cos}(x)+2\cdot\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e+C$$ or
$$u=-\frac{\operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{2\operatorname{cos}(x)}\right)-2\cdot\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e\operatorname{cos}(x)-4\cdot\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e-2C}{2\cdot\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e}$$ $\implies$
$$\frac{1}{y^3}=\frac{C-\operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{2\operatorname{cos}(x)}\right)}{2\cdot\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e}+\operatorname{cos}(x)+2$$ or
$$y=-\frac{\sqrt[3]2\cdot\sqrt[6\operatorname{cos}(x)]e}{\sqrt[3]{\operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{2\operatorname{cos}(x)}\right)-2\cdot\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e\operatorname{cos}(x)-4\cdot\sqrt[2\operatorname{cos}(x)]e-C}}$$ This is the required answer and the solution $y=0$ is achieved when $C=\infty$

Comment: When dividing by $y^4$, shouldn't it be $\frac{y'}{y^4}$ and not $\frac{y'}{4}$?  or did I miss a step?

Comment: @ewong corrected, thanks!

Comment: @abcdefu I couldn't understand the part where you equated $tsin(x)/2cos^2(x)+t′$ to 0. to find the equation for `t` and also in the next step using the same value of t(which make the above expression 0. To me this step seems the crux of the problem.